# Docker Volume Superset

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-superset

I want to persist the data (datatasets, graphs and dashboards) so that when the container is deleted they are not deleted and when I run it again they are present

My docker-compose:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
     
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - 2022:3306
   supeset:
    container_name: superset
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      MAPBOX_API_KEY: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFta2lsbHM1IiwiYSI6ImNrd293aDJyZjA3MGQyd3AzdTJpeXp0dTAifQ.w96chqjB6Nv3PW6_lpQVHQ'
      DATABASE_PORT: 2022
      DATABASE_DIALECT: 'mysql'  
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
    ports:
      - 8000:8088
    #volumes:
       ./superset-data:/app/pythonpath
```

No volumes are created locally and no data is stored in superset. I have looked in docker-hub and they do not specify the address of the volumes.
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset/

I **have updated my code** but the data still does not persist. I currently have this docker-compose
version: '2.4'

```
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
     
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - 2022:3306
 
  supeset:
    container_name: superset
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      MAPBOX_API_KEY: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamFta2lsbHM1IiwiYSI6ImNrd293aDJyZjA3MGQyd3AzdTJpeXp0dTAifQ.w96chqjB6Nv3PW6_lpQVHQ'
      DATABASE_DB: 'superset'
      DATABASE_HOST: 'mariadb'
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      DATABASE_USER: 'admin'
      DATABASE_PORT: 2022
      DATABASE_DIALECT: 'mysql'  
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you losing the data when you restart it? AFAICS the data is stored in mysql, so it should not be lost when you restart the container

Comment: Aren't you missing `DATABASE_HOST` or `MYSQL_HOST` env var?

Comment: What would be the value of this environment variable?

Comment: You should not use volumes in docker-compose to persist data?

Comment: Value should be "mariadb" which is the address of your mysql

Comment: I have changed my environment variables, but I still can't get the data to persist. You can see in the post. Thanks! Don't you think I would have to create some volume, or is it not necessary in superset?

Comment: Can you share the logs when both app starts using docker-compose?

Comment: If I do docker logs superset I get 
```
Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: `EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend for production deployments
2022-05-05 17:43:13,866:WARNING:superset.utils.cache_manager:Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: `EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend for pro

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2022:17:43:42 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2022:17:44:12 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/May/2022:17:44:42 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.74.0"

Comment: Can you update your question with formatted logs?

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice at this, I don't understand exactly what you want me to do. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that the environment variables are not properly configured and the volumes are not set?